# Trouble changing a fadeTo() to a fadeIn() in jQuery tools

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-effects

I'm using [jQuery Tools Scrollable with this setup](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html). I'm having trouble changing the transition effect on the large image.

When you click a thumbnail, the large image fades out-and-in (you can see this behaviour in the demo by [visiting the link](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html)). I the large image to fade in, only.

I assumed it's as simple as changing the transition in `var wrap = ... fadeTo()` to `fadeIn()`, but that's not the case. I also changed the transition on the `wrap.fadeTo()` line, and that did not work.

Any ideas why? I snipped unnecessary code from my example...

```
$(function() {
    $(".scrollable").scrollable();

    $(".items img").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

        var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");
        var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {
            wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);
            wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);
        };

        img.src = url;
        $(".items img").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }).filter(":first").click();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="image_wrap">Large image goes here</div>
<div class="scrollable">
    <div class="items">
        <div>
            thumbnails go here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `img`? And you can't add a `.load()` function to something that is already loaded, also if you add multiple `.load()` functions to 1 element and it will be loaded, all the `.load()` functions that you binded before will also be called.

And maybe you wan't to do a `.stop(true, false)` before you call the `.fadeTo()` methods, because if your already fading, it stops it, clears the queue and fades to the new position. So you don't have to wait untill it is partialy loaded.

**Update**

If you don't want the fadeout, but only the fade in use this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".scrollable").scrollable();

    $(".items img").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

        var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");
        var wrap = $("#image_wrap"); // This line edited
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {
            wrap.css("opacity", 0.5).fadeIn(); // This line edited
            wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);
        };

        img.src = url;
        $(".items img").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }).filter(":first").click();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, for the sake of brevity I snipped a lot of code. It's loading something from Flickr. I added the entire code block so it should be clearer what's going on now.

Comment: Updated my answer, if you want to fade something in, and don't fade out, you need to set the opacity back to 0.5 before it can fade in.

Comment: I'm afraid something is wrong. It's stuck at 0.5 opacity with no transition effects. The images switch normally with no transition, and the opacity is always at 0.5.

Comment: And if you change: `wrap.css("opacity", 0.5).fadeTo(1);`

Comment: Same as above :/ I really have no idea why!

Comment: I suspect it might have something to do with the onload event?

Comment: If i want to replace the fade effect with a slide effect already possible in jquerytools how do i do that , =(

Comment: change `fadeIn` to `slideDown`